# In English what's the difference between forward and toward

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I would like to know which sentence is correct, regarding the difference between the usage of *forward* and *toward*.
Should I write:
*I'm looking forward to September.*
 Or,
*I'm looking toward September?*

Thank you.

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: Both are correct, but notice that the first one needs _to_, but the second one doesn't. _Toward_ means motion or attention directed 'to; in the direction of' something that determines the direction, while _forward_ means directing motion or attention 'in the direction a human normally faces'. So _looking forward to September_ indicates that September is what you're anticipating (_look forward to_ is an idiom that means 'anticipate with pleasure'), while _looking toward September_ just means September is where your attention is focussed.

Answer (score 4):

In British English (I don't know whether it's the same in other regions):

> **I'm looking forward to September.**

This tends to mean that you are *anticipating a good and/or enjoyable experience* in (or beginning in) September. You may or may not be making plans or arrangements for the future event, but you are 'excited' about it.

> **I'm looking toward September.**

This tends to mean that you are *making plans or arrangements* for whatever is going to happen in September. The forthcoming event may or may not be especially enjoyable: it could be neutral, it could be unpleasant, it could be enjoyable. But mainly you are making plans.

Note that I have described differences in the ways in which these expressions are used, and what they are often intended to imply: but there is no especial *grammatical* difference between the two.